# Is it possible to up-class the generic in a typescript interface?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a bunch of services that are defined as

```
  export abstract class BaseService<T> {
      abstract getItem(id: string): T {}
  }


  export class FooService: BaseService<ADataModel> {
     getItem(id: string): ADataModel {} 
  }
```

when this gets reused in a specific project where `ADatatModel` needs extending, this works just fine

```
  export class SubClassedDataModel extends ADataModel {
}
```

Usually, extending the datamodel also requires extending the service to take the extra fields into account, like so

```
export class SubClassedService extends FooService {
}
```

However, the syntax in the project using the extended service becomes a bit tedious, because i have to cast explicitly the return values to the `SubClassedDataModel` type.

i.e. imagine `FooService` is provided as `SubClassedService`

```
 public myData: SubClassedDataModel;

 constructor(f: FooService) {
    this.myData = f.getItem('1') as SubClassedDataModel;
 }
```

Question: is there a way to tell `SubClassedService` to that it should treat T as `SubClassedDataModel`, while keeping any other references intact?

I.e. if another library service uses `FooService` it should still work on the type `MyDataModel`, while any accessor of FooService in the extension project sees it as `SubClassedDataModel`?

Preferably w/o redefining every function, or adding additional pr-usage code to the syntax.

Basically: Can I get to this:

```
 public myData: SubClassedDataModel;

 constructor(f: FooService) {
    this.myData = f.getItem('1');
 }
```

Comment: Not sure what in the context `constructor(f: FooService) {
    this.myData = f.getItem('1');
 }` should hint that `getItem` should be  `SubClassedDataModel`. Just the fact that it is assigned to `myData`?

Comment: I dont know.. I was hoping maybe there was some syntax on the base classes that could hint at it somehow. Or in the constructor mapping itself, i.e. `f: FooService<SubClassedDataObject>`.

Comment: Sure, you can do `FooService<SubClassedDataObject>` but that would mean `FooService` should be generic itself.

Comment: yeah, which it only really is based on the BaseService. I was hoping to expose fixed-type services, for ease of use. I.e. its known that FooService returns something that inherits on ADataModel, which is fine for 80% of uses, but when FooService is extended, it really returns something that inherits on SubClassedDataModel, which in turn inherits on ADataModel.

Comment: You *might* be able to get away with something using [polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types), but I wish the code here were a genuine [mcve] so I could just tweak it instead of having to spend time getting such an example in the first place.